# Shouldn't this gentleman be "The Grand Negus"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

The title of this fine gentleman with the majestic earlobes is *"The Grand Nagus"* (note the spelling):

[image]

Until recently, I always assumed his title was *"The Grand Negus"*, in order to match the English spelling and human definition of *Negus*:

> [**Wikipedia: Negus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negus) - Negus is a royal title in the Ethiopian Semitic languages. It denotes a monarch such as the Bahri Negus of the Medri Bahri in pre-1890 Eritrea and the Negus in pre-1974 Ethiopia. The title has subsequently been used to translate the words "king" or "emperor" in Biblical and other literature.

**Is there a reason for this difference in spelling, or is the similarity to the word to *Negus* just a coincidence?**

Comment: “Is there a reason for this difference in spelling” — yes. They’re Ferengi. They spell differently to Ethiopians.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Both Ferengian and Ehtiopian spelling is irrelevant due to the universal translators. _Nagus_ is neither the Ferengian spelling nor the pronunciation, it's the English translation as performed by the Universal Translators.

Comment: They probably changed the spelling because the Ferengi are already seen by some as politically incorrect Jewish caricatures and they didn't want to make the connection between them and any "Semitic" peoples any more obvious.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - They don’t seem to particularly resemble standard anti-Semitic caricatures to me. Well, I suppose they’re obsessed with commerce, which is certainly a feature of stereotypes about Jews, but besides that, is there anything else? No *kippot*, no beards, no *payot*, no long nose…they definitely seem to lack the common ones.

Comment: @Adamant No, not in terms of the character design. Mostly seems that way to me because the majority of Ferengi actors are Jewish in real life, combined the obsession with commerce you mentioned. Not caricatures, I suppose, just... a line can be drawn.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - It would be pretty reprehensible (though sadly not inconceivable: witness George Lucas deciding to make half his alien species have a specific accent for some reason) if the casting department specifically chose Jewish actors to play the Ferengi, relative to other roles. Is there evidence of this, though? It looks like two major Ferengi characters were played by actors with stereotypically Jewish names, but a lot of other Ferengi were not. Those numbers don’t seem large enough to reach a conclusion. I’d be more inclined to suspect coincidence.

Comment: For example, a number of Vulcans also seem to have been played by actors who were Jewish (either in practice or heritage), such as Leonard Nimoy, Mark Lenard, and Celia Lovsky. Perhaps there were just a decent number of Jewish people on Star Trek (though perhaps the Vulcans were also meant to be Jewish stereotypes: nothing is impossible). But it seems to me that when there’s a mercantile race, there might be a natural tendency to suspect that they represent Jews (because, well, at least some do, such as Tolkien’s dwarves). That doesn’t mean that such is always the case, though.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: This far, no farther.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No confirmed evidence

There does not appear to be an official statement from any of the *DS9* creative staff confirming that "Grand Nagus" comes from "Grand Negus".

It does, however, stand to reason that they would be connected.

## Spelling vs. transliteration

Since the question is focused on spelling, it should be pointed out that "negus" is a ***transliteration*** of an Ethiopian word, and so "negus" is simply a *preferred* English spelling.

## Nickname of Star Trek director David Livingston

Finally, it is interesting to note that "Nagus" was the nickname of David Livingston, the director of the *DS9* episode "The Nagus", according to *[The Star Trek Encyclopedia](https://books.google.ca/books?id=cbYf2l7gczUC&pg=PT1493&dq=Grand+nagus+Livingston+Star+Trek+encyclopedia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAGoVChMIl97VisbcxwIVQ4uSCh3Owgac#v=onepage&q=Grand%20nagus%20Livingston%20Star%20Trek%20encyclopedia&f=false)*.  Whether he was nicknamed before or after directing the episode is not stated.  It is known that *DS9* director of photography Marvin Rush used to call Livingston "the Nagus", which is fitting as Livingston is Star Trek's most prolific director, having directed over 60 Star Trek episodes in the *TNG* era.  It could be that his nickname (and its spelling) influenced the title of the character (or vice-versa).

Comment: Feel free to add in parts from my answer if you wish to - mine wasn't enough to stand up as an answer on its own :-)